# Connecting a Client Laptop to a AP-mode configured Laptop

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, wireless-access-point

I have two wil6210 (802.11ad) enabled laptops. I configure one of them in the AP mode and try to connect the client Laptop to the AP laptop. The client is unable to connect to the AP laptop. It connects briefly and then gets disconnected. After a couple of such tries it stops trying to connect to the AP. I run the AP mode using wpa_supplicant, and this is how the terminal output on the AP laptop looks like

```
>>sudo wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iwlp2s0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlp2s0 flags: No such device
Using interface wlp2s0 with hwaddr 04:ce:14:07:43:0a and ssid "AP_60ghz"
wlp2s0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
wlp2s0: AP-ENABLED 
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 04:ce:14:07:43:0a completed [id=0 id_str=]
wlp2s0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 04:ce:14:07:47:6b
wlp2s0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 04:ce:14:07:47:6b
wlp2s0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 04:ce:14:07:47:6b
wlp2s0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 04:ce:14:07:47:6b
```

The below is the Wireless Information gathered from the Client Laptop.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/25280558/

As can be seen, the 60 Ghz interface on the client is **wlp2s0**, and the SSID of the AP laptop, **AP_60ghz** is visible. However I am unable to establish a connection.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going wrong. I did not have a DHCP server running on my host machine, hence the client could not get an IP address.